# What is the best approach to render 3D model in iOS after facial landmark detection?

Tags: scenekit, ios11, augmented-reality, arkit, face-detection

I would like to place a hairstyle after facial landmark detection. I'm able to render 2D images properly. I would like to render 3D model. I thought of using SceneKit to render 3D model. I would like to know how Instagram, snapchat and other face filter apps are rendering 3D models. I observe SceneKit coordinate system is different from UIKit coordinate system. I have googled but couldn't find the conversion of coordinate system. Could anyone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `worldUp` and `simdWorldUp` instance properties to understand how ARKit constructs a scene coordinate system based on real-world device motion (also, you can inspect `ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment` enum).

Please, look at this SO post: [Understand coordinate spaces in ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449012/understand-coordinate-spaces-in-arkit) for complete info.

And remember, `ARAnchor` is your best friend when placing 3D object. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155379/whats-the-difference-between-using-aranchor-to-insert-a-node-and-directly-inser)
 for further details.

Comment: Hello, I don't know if I need to recreate same question but what will be the response to this question on MacOS (so without ARKit and without TrueDepth camera) ? Thanks

Comment: I didn't try it in macOS. So, you'd better recreate this question for macOS.